# What is a convolution transform?

Tags: mathematical-physics, quantum-optics

In quantum optics, on talks about the nonclassicality of a field in terms of the $P$, $Q$ and $R$ functions. The the $P$ and $R$ functions are related as

$R(z,\tau) = \frac{1}{\pi \tau} \int d^2w ~\exp(-\frac{|z-w|^2}{\tau})~P(w).$

This is often called as the $convolution$ transformation between $P$ and $Q$. I want to know what exactly a $convolution$ transformation means?

Comment: The convolution of two functions is a well-known mathematical object, given two (suitably regular) functions $f,g$, their convolution $f\!*\!g$ is a function defined by $f\!*\!g(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} f(y)g(x-y) \mathrm{d}y$ (equivalently the role of $f,g$ can be interchanged with the same outcome).

Comment: See  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_transform, the convolution operation with a gaussian. This effectively comes down to smoothing/blurring.